# Cannot trigger event handler with ApplScript in ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.iChat

Tags: applescript

so I have this script in the ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.iChat

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat
        display dialog "good, received reply"
    end message received
end using terms from
```

I do receive the message in the Messages app, but cannot see this script triggered.

btw found these
https://github.com/ZekeSnider/Jared/issues/20
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318230/did-apple-remove-the-applescript-handler-option-in-macos-high-sierra

This is macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.
In system preferences -> security & privacy -> privacy -> Accessibility, I did add "Script Editor" based on some posts.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you look in Messages > Preferences, it no longer has an 'AppleScript handler' option to be triggered based on the event as it used to have in earlier releases of the OS.

Comment: @user3439894 so if I want to wait for the "message received" event, is there any other ways (other than AppleScript) to do it in Mac ?